# Create HTML Element with ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For an application i want to create Object-Based components in `ES6`.

On the normal way, you can create Elements as follow:

```
var element = document.createElement('YourElement');
element.innerHTML = 'Content';
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(element);
```

How i can create these in `ES6` like:

```
export default class Container extends HTMLDivElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.innerHTML = 'Content';
    }   
}
```

With these example?

```
var container = new Container();
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(container);
```

My idea is, to create an **-only JavaScript-** UI Framework, without using "native" HTML snippets...

Comment: Updated snip to meet the 'HTML snippets' you mentioned - run below

Comment: ES6 still uses the "normal way"

Answer (score 3):

```html
<div class='body'>

</div>

<script>
class Container extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log( 'Constructed' )
    }   
    connectedCallback() {
      console.log('Callback');
      this.innerHTML = "Content";
    }
}
customElements.define('my-contain', Container);
let container = new Container();
document.querySelector('.body').appendChild(container);
</script>
```

You need to register your Component with the `CustomElementRegistry` below your Class definition and utilize the `connectedCallback()`.

```
export default class Container extends HTMLDivElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.innerHTML = 'Content'; // Does Nothing
    } 
    connectedCallback() { // Fires when attached
      console.log('Callback');
      this.innerHTML = "Content";
    }  
}

customElements.define('my-contain', Container, { extends: "div" });
```

LIFECYCLE HOOKS OF CUSTOM COMPONENTS
[image]

More info on CustomElementRegistry here: [MDN CustomElementRegistry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry)

More info on implementation of such here: [MDN Using Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

Comment: It's only the way to define the extended Element via `customElements.define`? My brain says, that you only need `extends` on the `ES6` class to extend an available Object... But thanks for the tip!

Comment: Note that a custom element has to have a hyphen in its name as well.

Comment: namebased specification already knowing, because i had created custom elements days/months/years ago - Validators will flag custom elements without hyphen-names as Error..

Comment: @AdrianPreuss answer also updated to reflect removal of the extends on `customElement` definition.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss Yes. You normally don't use custom classes to create DOM elements…